# How to: add a class docstring with Eclipse/Pydev via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pydev

*What I want:*
Press a keyboard shortcut that auto-creates the class docstring snippet:

```
class SomeClass:
    '''
    <cursor>
    '''
```

*What I tried:*
When my cursor is on a function definition, I can press `cmd+1`.
This displays a pop-up menu with `Make docstring` as an option.
Choosing it creates a docstring snippet just like seen above.
This works perfectly for functions - not however for classes from what I tried.

Any hints/solutions are welcome. :)

| Mac OS X Version: 10.7.3
| Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2
| Pydev Plugin Version: 2.4.0.20120101

Comment: FWIW it does work for classes on my Ubuntu in Aptana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it seems you found a bug (please report that at the PyDev sf tracker).

The problem is that if you have something as:

```
class MyClass:
  pass
```

it does NOT work, but if you have something as:

```
class MyClass(object):
  pass
```

it does work properly... so, the issue is that PyDev didn't consider that line to be a class line in that case.

Edit: This is fixed for PyDev 2.5.0 (which is already released).

Comment: I updated PyDev to 2.5.x and it is working now. :)
Thank you!